# Use sequence number with insert select

Tags: oracle, sequence

I'm trying to execute the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO mySchema.ODI_PRICELIST_THREAD_TABLE
(
     src_table,
     thread_id,
     creation_date
)
    SELECT DISTINCT
           source_table AS src_table,
           num_thread_seq.nextval AS THREAD_ID,
           create_date AS CREATION_DATE
      FROM mySchema.nb_pricelist_ctrl
```

I need the `THREAD_ID` field to be a number from 1 to X where X is defined in runtime therefore I've used a sequence from 1 to X (I'm using ODI).
However, I keep having the **ORA-02287** Sequence not allowed error...

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125936/oracle-sql-use-sequence-in-insert-with-select-statement) question and I still can't figure how I can fix my problem.
I've been seaching but I'm having no luck with finding a solution. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyword `distinct` is incompatible with sequence querying. If you really need it, try something like

```
INSERT INTO mySchema.ODI_PRICELIST_THREAD_TABLE (
 src_table,
 thread_id,
 creation_date)
select 
  a.src_table,
  num_thread_seq.nextval,
  a.create_date
from
  (select distinct src_table, create_date from mySchema.nb_pricelist_ctrl) a
```

Comment: It isn't important. I'll add insert for disambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

From OraFaq :

The following are the cases where you can't use a sequence:

> For a SELECT Statement:
>
> - In a WHERE clause
> - In a GROUP BY or ORDER BY clause
> - **In a DISTINCT clause**
> - Along with a UNION or INTERSECT or MINUS
> - In a sub-query

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-02287

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO mySchema.ODI_PRICELIST_THREAD_TABLE
(
     src_table,
     thread_id,
     creation_date
)
    SELECT DISTINCT
           source_table AS src_table,
           num_thread_seq.nextval() AS THREAD_ID,
           create_date AS CREATION_DATE
      FROM mySchema.nb_pricelist_ctrl
```